# How can I make these tables sturdier for cheap?

Tags: wood

I have multiple tables like this for my vegetable garden. They serve their purpose but I’d like them to be more stable. The 5 ft vertical posts are very wobbly and that’s a big part of my concern.

[image]

Comment: add diagonal bracing.

Comment: Will 1 on both sides do it?

Comment: It may be enough for you - how will I know, if not then X bracing...

Answer (score 3):

I can see a couple of options, diagonal bracing is one - shown as the brown X, a joint between the two braces where they cross will also help.

But another option can be re-inforcing triangles in the corners shown in blue - these can be larger if you wish, also depends on the strength of the horizontal member.

[image]

Comment: What should I use for the corner triangles? And would that make the vertical posts more stable? I almost want to rebuild all the tables but it will take too much time.

Comment: Does not have to be a full triangle... But plywood or 2*1 or suitable size... Stability was the whole point of your original question...

Comment: On the top left below the vote number and up & down arrows is a tick symbol, usually in grey until you use it, goes green when you have ticked it.